# c# http Post not getting anything in webresponse

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Here's my code for Request and Response.

```
System.IO.MemoryStream xmlStream = null;
HttpWebRequest HttpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
xmlStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(format));

byte[] buf2 = xmlStream.ToArray();
System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8Enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
string s = UTF8Enc.GetString(buf2);
string sPost = "XMLData=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(s);
byte[] bPostData =  UTF8Enc.GetBytes(sPost);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
HttpReq.Timeout = 30000;  
request.Method = "POST"; 
request.KeepAlive = true; 
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream()) 
{
    requestStream.Write(bPostData, 0, bPostData.Length); 
    requestStream.Close(); 
}

string responseString = "";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) 
{ 
    responseString = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
}
```

No part of this code crashes. The "format" string is the one with XML in it. By the end when you try to see what's in the `responseString`, it's an empty string. I am supposed to see the XML sent back to me from the URL. Is there something missing in this code?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a simplification of this messy code:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "XMLData", format }
    };
    byte[] resultBuffer = client.UploadValues(url, values);
    string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultBuffer);
}
```

and if you wanted to upload the XML directly in the POST body you shouldn't be using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as content type. You probably should specify the correct content type, like this:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/xml";
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(format);
    byte[] resultBuffer = client.UploadData(url, data);
    string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultBuffer);
}
```

Comment: i cant send in namevaluecollection. I need to send an XML

Comment: @lkwewpp, it's an XML that's being sent in my example. Did you try it? If the `format` variable contains XML, the WebClient will use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST request and send the XML in the `XMLData` field and take care of properly encoding it. And if you want to send the XML in the POST body then you shouldn't use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` at all.