# MonoTouch: WebConnection crash on resume

Tags: c#, .net, mono, crash, xamarin.ios

I have been experiencing the following crash while using MonoTouch on an iPad. I have tested on iOS 4.2+ and it seems to happen on all versions of iOS. This is a very difficult one to reproduce so I do not have a good test case. However, I have received numerous crashes when resuming the application. You can see the call stack received for this crash below:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
   at System.Net.WebConnection.NextRead () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
   at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.ReadAll () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
   at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.CheckResponseInBuffer () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
   at System.Net.WebConnection.ReadDone (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I have all of my application network access wrapped in try/catch blocks and are synchronous connections happening on a separate thread, which is why this call stack has me stumped!

If anyone has seen this or knows the cause please let me know. If you have any suggestions for working around it I would love to hear those as well!

Here is an example of a standard thread operation; keep in mind that all of this code is wrapped in a try/catch:

```
HttpWebRequest r = new HttpWebRequest(Configuration.MasterRequestUri);
r.UserAgent = Configuration.UserAgent;
r.Method = "POST";
r.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
r.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
r.Timeout = 10000;
r.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000;
r.CachePolicy = Configuration.CachePolicy;

r.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
r.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

Stream s = r.GetRequestStream();
s.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
s.Flush ();
s.Close ();

WebResponse wr = r.GetResponse();
s = wr.GetResponseStream();

using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
{
    string responseString = sr.ReadToEnd();
    // Parses the string and what not
}
```

Comment: Look at where you are calling Stream s = r.GetRequestStream question does this create a new stream if not write Stream s = null; then new the instance of r, do the same for wr also what line is the error actually happening.. can you Debug this and see where the Instance error is occurring ? also what is the name of the file or files that you are looking for..error states that unknown file name

Comment: Thanks for the reply DJ. Take a peek at the call stack at the top,  actually the error is happening inside the Mono WebConnection.cs file during a read attempt. It does not give me any additional information and does not show the entry point from my application; which is very odd.

Comment: still looks a bit odd for starters can you check to make sure you are getting anything in wr where you do r.GetResponse() wondering also if this could be a url encoding issue.. but check to see if s has anything can you do any Response.Writes to check.. looks like in your StreamReader sr you are creating the StreamReader but you are trying to assing the value of sr.ReadtoEnd to a string I would look at reading the sr into a List<string> or some other collection but just doesn't look right I could be wrong

Comment: try this link and see if you can change your code to match the example which was a previous post on StackOverFlow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077862/c-sharp-http-post-not-getting-anything-in-webresponse

Comment: Thanks DJ. My issue is a bit different; the code I posted works 99% of the time and when it has an HTTP error it is handled gracefully with logic in the try/catch. The problem is in very rare situations there is a crash while resuming the app and since the debugger cannot connect at this point I am left with only the call stack I posted above.

Comment: there must be something that you are missing and or not releasing.. the code wrapped in the using() is fine releases it self.. perhaps when you are doing this repeatedly you have open file handles or something I would do a check to see if variables !=null that you have created..then null them.. that seems to be the only other thing that I can think of...

Comment: The error itself is being thrown inside the Mono framework. I am going to be re-visiting this in the coming weeks so I will post back if I have any additional insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue went away on its own in later versions of Xamarin (MonoTouch) so I assume this was a bug in the version of Mono being used at the time.